# Java determine limit of repeating a function

Tags: java, function

In Java, I have an interface that takes in a `double` and returns a `double`, like a mathematical function. Now, I have a double to start with. I want to determine whether or not, if I repeat the function over and over, the results will converge to either infinity (`+/-`). For example, I could have the function `n = n ^ 2`. That way, starting with 2, the sequence would go:

```
2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...
```

And converge to infinity. If I started with 0.1 however, the sequence would go:

```
0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001...
```

And not converge to infinity.

I want a method that takes in a `Function<Double, Double>` and a `double`, and returns a boolean as to whether or not repeating this function has results leading to infinity or negative infinity.

**UPDATE** Code:

```
boolean goesToInfinity(Function fn, double dbl) {
    double last = dbl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) { // repeats 25 times
        dbl = fn.apply(dbl);
        if (Math.abs(dbl) < Math.abs(last)) return false;
        last = dbl;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, this returns false if the function is `x -> x - 1` and the `dbl` is 1, since the values are `1, 0, -1...` and the code sees `1, 0` and returns false.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: @Jashaszun The code won't halt if the number doesn't go to infinity; rather, it will keep going towards another number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible. For any implementation of this function that you want to write, I can pass it a function of my own that will break your implementation.

See [the Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems).

An example of a function that would break your implementation is a function that says

> if Fermat's Last Theorem is true, then x => infinity
>
> otherwise, return x => 0

Since Fermat's Last Theorem is not (as of yet) proven, your implementation cannot solve my example function. Therefore, any implementation you write cannot be a general one.

Comment: You can't "break the implementation". It either returns true or false for any function and any starting input.

Comment: @JamesSmith It can't possibly. See my example.